# How to Display Part of a set of Filtered Objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, filtering

Sorry if I replicate, but I'm having a hard time wording this for a decent query.

I'm trying to filter a set of complex objects through an `ICollectionView` and then display each object that made it through, represented by one of their properties. In this particular example, the collection is a list of `ComplexClass` objects, each of which containing a `Name` and `Number` property. I wish to represent each in a `ListBox`, sitting within a `Popup`, by their `Name`.

Here's the XAML code for the `MainWindow`:

```
<Window
    x:Name="mainWindow"
    x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:test="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="buttonStack">
            <Button x:Name="popupButton" Click="popupButton_Click" Content="Pop-up!" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Button x:Name="randomInsertButton" Click="randomInsertButton_Click" Content="Random Addition!"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Popup x:Name="testPopup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=popupButton}" PopupAnimation="Scroll" Placement="Left" 
               AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid>
                <Button x:Name="popupsButton"  Content="Button" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ListBox x:Name="testListBox" Height="100" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source=strings}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="testListBox_Selected"/>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The `MainWindow`'s code-behind:

```
namespace TestWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static List<ComplexClass> stringList = new List<ComplexClass>();
        public ObservableCollection<ComplexClass> strings;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            stringList.Add(new ComplexClass("apple",0));
            stringList.Add(new ComplexClass("bat",2));
            stringList.Add(new ComplexClass("cattle",6));
            stringList.Add(new ComplexClass("dogma",5));

            strings = new ObservableCollection<ComplexClass>(stringList);
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = strings;
            testListBox.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
        }

        private void popupButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(strings);
            view.Filter =
                //null;
                (o) =>
                {
                    return (o as ComplexClass).Name!=string.Empty;
                };
            view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Descending));
            testPopup.IsOpen = !testPopup.IsOpen;
        }

        private void randomInsertButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            stringList.Add(stringList[r.Next(0, stringList.Count)]);
            strings.Add(stringList.Last());
        }

        private void testListBox_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComplexClass selected =(ComplexClass)(sender as ListBox).SelectedItem;
            stringList.Add(selected);
            strings.Add(selected);
        }

    }
}
```

And finally, the `ComplexClass` code:

```
namespace TestWPF
{
    public class ComplexClass
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int Number { get; private set; }

        public ComplexClass(string name, int number)
        {
            Name = name;
            Number = number;
        }
    }
}
```

What it's currently doing is displaying each of the objects as if they've been ToString()-ed: "TestWPF.ComplexClass".

I actually want them to be displayed as:

dogma

cat

bat

apple

in that order.

Can I get some help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues here.

First, you are binding to the list in your XAML:

```
<ListBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding Source=strings}" ... />
```

but then also setting the binding in code:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = strings;
testListBox.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

You need to do one or the other: I'd suggest binding in XAML, and removing the binding stuff from the code-behind.

Second, the `ComplexClass` items are being ToString-ified because that's the default behaviour of a `ListBoxItem` when supplied with content (the items in a WPF `ListBox` are wrapped inside `ListBoxItem` elements). The easiest way for you to fix this is to set the `DisplayMemberPath` property on the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding Source=strings}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ... />
```

Comment: Okay, I did both of those, and now, for some reason, the `ListBox` displays nothing. The selections are there, but I can't see anything; each selection is blank. UPDATE:oddly enough, when I put the procedural binding code back, each selection appears.

Comment: So is it working now then? ie. displaying the name instead of the ToString version?

Comment: Yes, but why do I now have to do binding in two places?

Comment: You shouldn't. Personally I would put the binding in the XAML and remove it from the code. I would change your constructor to create `stringList` and `strings` **before** the call to `InitializeComponent`, and also put `DataContext = this;` before that method call and remove the `DataContext` property setter from the `ListBox` XAML.

Comment: Does the `DataContext=this` code make it so that all the XAML for that window knows this beforehand, in such that I can use `Source = "whatever"`, and it will point to the `Window` automatically? I'm still not secure in the WPF architecture yet.

Comment: Most XAML elements have a `DataContext` property. This is inherited by child elements, so if you set the property on the **Window** it will be inherited by the outer **Grid**, the **Popup**, the inner **Grid** and eventually the **ListBox**. Then you can set your bindings without needing to set the binding Source, ie. just set the binding Path. You can set the `DataContext` either through code or XAML: usually I specify it in code.